# Checking for list membership with Pytables where method

Tags: python, hdf5, pytables

I'm trying to select rows based on multiple criterion that cannot be easily expressed with the conditional statements that [pytables allow]
(http://pytables.github.io/usersguide/condition_syntax.html).

I also don't want to format a really long string as a conditional argument because that seems hacky.

So I was trying to collect the rows in an array, hoping that I can do additional selection on rows

```
my_list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
my_list2 = ['5', '6', '7']

rows_selected = []
for an_item in my_list1:
    for row in table_all.where("letters == an_item"):
        for another_item in my_list2:
            if row['numbers'] == another_item:
                print row
                rows_selected.append(row)
```

This type of setting would work (although not really ellegant). But the problem is, all of the rows collected in  `rows_selected` lose their identity and become the last assigned row. So basically I end up with a list of duplicate rows.

Is there an elegant way of using list membership as selection criteria for pytables? Or how can I circumvent the duplicate row thing and make sure the rows collected inside the loop remain unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just use `an_item` in your conditional. It doesnt not change with the loop. I am surprised you even got anything out, i.e.

`table_all.where("letters == an_item")`

should be

`table_all.where("letters == %s" % an_item)`

Why don't you try something like

`row_selected = [ table_all.readWhere("(letters == %s) & (numbers == %s)" % (l, n) ) for l in my_list1 for n in my_list2 ]`

this should be much faster than what you have there and is much more elegant

Comment: Thanks, this does look more elegant. A few things though: First, the syntax I wrote `table_all.where("letters == an_item")` actually works because the interpreter somehow expects the name of a variable there (at least in my case). Following this, I had to modify your conditions string so that they will indeed be interpreted as variable names. Like this: `table_all.readWhere("(letters == '%s') & (numbers == '%s')" % (l, n) ) for l in my_list1 for n in my_list2 ]`